# Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How to setup multiple authentication in Laravel 5.3 for two different tables(Users and Admin).

By default Laravel has User Model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to implements roles. You can use the default Laravel User Model and will need to create a Role Model:

User Model

```
...
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_roles', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}

public function inRole($role) {
    return (bool) $this->role()->where('name', '=', $role)->count();
}
...
```

Role Model

```
...
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
...
```

You gonna need to create 2 tables in addition to your users table:

```
Table users

id | name
---------
1  | John
2  | Michael

Table roles

id | name
---------
1  | Admin
2  | Member

Table user_roles

id | user_id | role_id
----------------------
1  |    1    |    1   
2  |    2    |    1
```

Now you can implement different permissions for the different roles you have. You can define the permissions using Policies or Gates. For more info how to do that check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization).

Now to redirect your members to /users/home and admins to /admin/dashboard you can do the following:

You define adminAccess in your AuthServiceProvider:

```
public function boot() {
    $this->registerPolicies();
    ...

    // Define adminAccess
    Gate::define('adminAccess', function ($user) {
        return $user->inRole('admin');
    });
}
```

**Update:**
Now you can protect your admin routes with a Middleware like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->inRole('admin')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Then register the Middleware in your Kernal.php in the `$routeMiddleware` variable. Then you can place all your admin routes in a group and use the middleware there:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth']) {
    // Define your routes
}
```

Comment: How can i redirect based on roles. User will be redirected to users/home and admin will be redirected to admin/dashboard and restricting users having roles as members cannot view admin dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you need multi auth based on guards, try this package for laravel 5.3 https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth