# One Login page for different types of users and redirects to their intended dashboards in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've been planning to make one login page for different types of users and it will be able to direct them to their intended dashboards/homepages.  These are my two users:

1. Traveler
2. Agent

The traveler can successfully login and will be directed to the intended homepage BUT the Agent wont be directed to its intended homepage instead it will be directed back to the login page.

This is my code of the Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Travelers;
use App\Agents;
use App\Users;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
            if(Auth::attempt([
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password
            ])){   
                $user = Users::where('email', $request->email)->first();

                switch ($user->userType){
                    case 'traveler':
                        return redirect()->route('Traveler/HomePage');
                        break;
                    case 'travel agent':
                        return redirect()->route('Agent/HomePage');
                        break;
                }
            }
            else{
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: what version of laravel you on?

Comment: [How best to redirect Admins from Users after Login & Authentication](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-best-to-redirect-admins-from-users-after-login-authentication?page=1)

Comment: Add a catch all 'default' to your switch control structure. What is the result of Auth for agent?

Comment: [Redirect admin and users to different pages after login](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-best-to-redirect-admins-from-users-after-login-authentication?page=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 Login redirect to different pages for multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048732/laravel-5-3-login-redirect-to-different-pages-for-multiple-users)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile im using laravel 5.5.20

Comment: Did you check credential for **travel agent** ? According to your code, If the credential is wrong then it will redirect to **login** page.

Comment: @AmanullahAman yes, i did :)

Comment: @LaravelBegginer Write **dd($user)** before **switch** and try to login using  **travel agent** credential and, see what result come. We need to go step by step :)

Comment: @AmanullahAman, i have already tried it, still went back to the login page.

Comment: @LaravelBegginer If you tried **dd($user)** and get no result, then I think it's your login credential problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to redefine method `redirectPath` in `LoginController`
For example:

```
public function redirectPath() 
{  
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
        return '/admin';
    }

    return '/';
}
```

Comment: im gonna try this. is after "redirectPath" really empty?

Comment: Can't understand, what you mean?

Comment: The parenthesis beside "redirectPath" :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you add `user_type` column to `user` table and `1 - users / 2 - admin`

LoginController.php

```
//protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(Auth::user()->user_type=='2'){
       return '/dashboard';
    }else{
       return '/game';
    }
}
```

all the `admins` redirect to `dashboard` and other `users` to `game`. I am using laravel default auth system.

note that 
`protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';` 
 changed to

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return '/path';
}
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authentication-quickstart