# User and admin role in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

In my laravel project, I want some admin and user role. I want to make user login in different routes after login. And also for admin also. How should I do it?

Comment: Have you actually done *any* research?

Comment: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust - All you have to do is look on Google ;)

Comment: You should check that link it's all explained
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543967/multiple-authentication-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 2):

You should first make 3 table in your database; user, role and user_role. user_role table has many to many relationship. Then you will make a middleware that checks your role checks when login. In your route, you use that middleware in login's post.

See details about middle ware in laravel 5.3 documentation.
https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can try [laravel 5.3 boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate). It comes with a full featured access control system out of the box with an easy to learn API and is built on a Twitter Bootstrap foundation with a front and backend architecture.